# discord.py wrong command message

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm having some issues making a custom error message when a wrong command is used on discord.

The code is:

```
@client.event
async def on_message_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound):
        await ctx.send("Unknown command")
```

If I use wrong command, the following will appear in the console:

> Ignoring exception in command None:
> discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "wrong command" is not found

But the discord bot does not send the *"Unknow command"* message.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: its on_command_error not on_message_error

Answer (score 0):

Like Łukasz said, replace your `on_message_error` with `on_command_error`. You can view this in [the docs here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=on_command_error#discord.on_command_error).

```py
@client.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandNotFound): # or discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound as you wrote
        await ctx.send("Unknown command")
```